# How can I query an ID-Name pair in LINQ for duplicate names?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a LINQ to Objects query that returns a list of:

```
class EmpMasterIDocBuffer
{
  public int Index { get; set; }
  public Int64 AutoId { get; set; }
  public string Buffer { get; set; }
}
```

It is correctly ordered so that duplicate Buffer values will be easily visible in a grid, but how can I query it? AutoId will also be duplicate when Buffer is duplicate, e.g.

1 - Fred

2 - Mary

2 - Mary

3 - Jane

4 - Bill

But Index will always be unique.

I have removed `Index`, as it was just an idea I was toying with, but this is my actual code, and it returns zero items, while I know there are at least three identical classes.

```
var docs = ctx.Database.SqlQuery<SapIdocEmployeeNumber>("select AutoId, IDoc.query('data(ZHREMPMASTER/IDOC/ZHRSA_EMPMASTER01000/BUFFER)') AS Buffer from SAPIDocs").Where(i => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(i.EmployeeNumber)).ToList();
var lastDup = docs
  //.Where(i => i.AutoId == 42)
  .GroupBy(i => i.EmployeeNumber)
  .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
  .Select(g => g.Last());
```

Pasting this has given me a clue! I must only check for duplicates in the first eight characters.

Comment: You can use `Distinct`

Comment: Distinct will remove duplicates. I want to identify them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me, the answer of Tim Schmelter is the best. I only have a small modification. Just in case the Buffer properties are the same but the AutoId is not, that item still will be included although it's not a duplicate. Instead of grouping by the Buffer, group the items by an anonymous type containing the properties you want:

```
//'list' is the list with items
var duplicates = list.GroupBy(x => new { x.AutoId, x.Buffer })
                     .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
                     .Select(s => s.First());
```

So in the case the class will have more properties and they're only duplicates if all property-values are equal, this method will take that into account. Just add the properties to the anonymous object in the GroupBy-clause.

Answer (score 5):

> ...so that duplicate Buffer values will be easily visible in a grid, but
>   how can I query it?

So you want to show duplicates?

You can use `GroupBy`:

```
var duplicates = buffers
    .GroupBy(b => b.Buffer)
    .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
    .Select(g => g.First()):
```

If you instead want to show non-duplicates use `g.Count() == 1`.

If you want to remove duplicates:

```
var uniques = buffers
    .GroupBy(b => b.Buffer)
    .Select(g => g.First()):
```

Comment: "So you want to how duplicates?" What are you trying to say here?

Comment: @RononDex: Should be "show", thanks. The `s` went away somehow.

Answer (score 0):

distinct will not work in case of linq to object there are two options one is group by and other is Comparer as shown below

```
namespace Application.Core.Common
{
using System.Collections.Generic;
public class EmpMasterIDocBufferComparer : IEqualityComparer<EmpMasterIDocBuffer>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Equality check
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="x">EmpMasterIDocBuffer x</param>
    /// <param name="y">EmpMasterIDocBuffer y</param>
    /// <returns>Returns true false</returns>
    public bool Equals(EmpMasterIDocBuffer x, EmpMasterIDocBuffer y)
    {
        if (x.Index== y.ANUPFROM
            && x.AutoId == y.ANUPTOM
            && x.Buffer== y.Buffer, System.StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// To get hash code
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="obj">ANSU object</param>
    /// <returns>UTYP id</returns>
    public int GetHashCode(EmpMasterIDocBuffer obj)
    {
        return obj == null ? 0 : obj.Index;
    }
}
```

}

and while calling distinct call as below way

```
IEqualityComparer<EmpMasterIDocBuffer> comparer = new EmpMasterIDocBufferComparer();
        var distinctList = EmpMasterIDocBufferCollection.Distinct(comparer).ToList();
```

Comment: Don't only primitive types have default comparers?